# Changing color of specific tab of top menu in wordpress

Tags: navigation, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using wordpress. I am messed up with a problem and still i am unable to find it's solution. I am trying to change color of only 1 tab in whole navigation menu ! 
I mean if my navigation bar include 5 tabs and i want to highlight one tab with a specific background color. But i don't have any idea to do this. Can you suggest some solution to this ? ! Thanks in advance .......

Regards,

Comment: Normally you can do this editing the css in wps stylesheet editor; I don't know what to change as that depends on the theme you are using -- you should get started searching the wordpress-forums: http://en.forums.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a menu in wordpress it will assign it an id and a class, like this:

```
<li id="menu-item-1704" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-1704"><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=118">Home</a></li>
```

Each "menu-item" will always have a unique id number.

So then you need to add this to your css and only that particular menu item will be changed:

```
#menu-item-1704{background:red;}
```